# Two-column note

Tags: two-column, columns, notes

I have to write a thesis and I want to use Latex but I don't know how to do this thing:

I want to write a one-column text in the top of the document, and I want to create a table with 2 column that contain all the notes refers the content of the top of the document.
The notes written below must be follow the text (thus if the text go in another page, also the note must go in another page), and I have to choose in which column a note should go.

Can I do this in Latex? If yes, how?

Thanks for the help

---

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{report}
    \usepackage[italian]{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
    \usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text

    \usepackage{tabularx}

    \begin{document}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\ap{1}. Praesent lectus sem, consequat a malesuada id, commodo quis ligula. Quisque quis mi sed turpis aliquam fermentum. Vivamus dui diam, sodales quis egestas nec, malesuada sagittis eros\ap{2}. Praesent eget aliquet nisi. Duis sit amet velit molestie, fermentum nibh eget, pulvinar erat\ap{3}. Quisque a congue ligula, tempus venenatis tortor. Vivamus lobortis odio nunc, et blandit nunc imperdiet at. Aenean interdum commodo odio, eu aliquam urna fermentum in. Praesent\ap{4} in placerat enim. Quisque scelerisque augue nec gravida mattis. Praesent sit amet nisl tempus, venenatis ante commodo, tristique turpis. Phasellus quis sem rutrum, sollicitudin velit sed, hendrerit quam\ap{5}. Maecenas vehicula erat sed massa maximus, quis cursus orci tempor. Mauris lobortis arcu tellus, interdum efficitur nibh molestie in. Praesent\ap{6} nec ipsum et nulla vehicula posuere non in nulla.

    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |X|X| }

     \hline
     Left Note & Right Note \\
     \hline
     1) this the first left note bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  & 4) this the first right note bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \\
     \hline
     3) this is the second left note bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  & 2) this is the second right note bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \\
     \hline
     5) this is the third left note bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  & 6) this is the third right note bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \\
     \hline

    \end{tabularx}

    \end{document}
```

NOTE: this is only an example to show the layout, I can do this also with the footnote command but I don't know how.

The important fact is that the note must follow the text (as I said above)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Can you show an approximation of what you have in mind?

Comment: I have added a little example to show the idea

Comment: Besides \noindent, how do you want to improve on this?  One could put the entire tabular inside a float, but it would be all or nothing as to fitting it on the page.

Comment: BTW, where is \ap defined?  "Search in files" finds nothing.

Comment: \ap is only to write an apex.
\\
the \noindent command is not a problem, I need to create a table that contain only the note of the same page that contains the table, and I wand to do this dynamically, so if I change 2/3 rows I don't have to change the whole document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution:

```
\footnotetext{\hspace{-2em}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}%
    \setcounter{enumi}{0}
    \item Left footnote
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}%
    \setcounter{enumi}{0}
    \item Right footnote
\end{minipage}
}
```

With this code each footnote follows its word

Answer (score 0):

You might find this amuslng.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
    \usepackage[italian]{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
    \usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
    \usepackage{afterpage}

    \usepackage{tabularx}

    \begin{document}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\ap{1}. Praesent lectus sem, consequat a malesuada id, commodo quis ligula. Quisque quis mi sed turpis aliquam fermentum. Vivamus dui diam, sodales quis egestas nec, malesuada sagittis eros\ap{2}. Praesent eget aliquet nisi. Duis sit amet velit molestie, fermentum nibh eget, pulvinar erat\ap{3}. Quisque a congue ligula, tempus venenatis tortor. Vivamus lobortis odio nunc, et blandit nunc imperdiet at. Aenean interdum commodo odio, eu aliquam urna fermentum in. Praesent\ap{4} in placerat enim. Quisque scelerisque augue nec gravida mattis. Praesent sit amet nisl tempus, venenatis ante commodo, tristique turpis. Phasellus quis sem rutrum, sollicitudin velit sed, hendrerit quam\ap{5}. Maecenas vehicula erat sed massa maximus, quis cursus orci tempor. Mauris lobortis arcu tellus, interdum efficitur nibh molestie in. Praesent\ap{6} nec ipsum et nulla vehicula posuere non in nulla.

\footnotetext[0]{\hspace{-2em}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |X|X| }
     \hline
     Left Note & Right Note \\
     \hline
     1) this the first left note bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  & 4) this the first right note bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \\
     \hline
     3) this is the second left note bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  & 2) this is the second right note bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \\
     \hline
     5) this is the third left note bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla  & 6) this is the third right note bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla \\
     \hline
\end{tabularx}}

\end{document}
```

[image: full page]

Comment: yeah but I want to connect the notes in the text with the row in the table (like the footnote) but I don't know how choose the side of the footnote.

however thanks for the response, I'll try this way if I don't find anything else,